# client-server application

Tags: android, client

I have to create an application server client in android(both the client an server are on android) but I'm quite new to this-can someone help me out with some information?
Can TCP/IP be used for connecting the server and the client or in android I should use something else?
If I'm using 2 emulators each of them on different systems,can I send data between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android uses the Linux TCP/IP stack, so you should be able to use the standard `java.net.Socket` object if you wish, and any of your preferred I/O stream readers/writers in Java.

In fact, you can probably follow most Java tutorials for socket programming in Linux and be completely okay for Android. Search Google for an "echo server" example (it's the "Hello World" equivalent to TCP/IP sockets).

Comment: Just a second.I'm running my emulators on windows:)

Comment: @adrian: Java is a platform-independent language. It doesn't matter whether you're on Windows, Linux, or Mac. You can still use `java.net.Socket` just the same. Besides, if your client AND server are both on the Android platform, then it really doesn't matter what OS you're using to write the software. Android uses the Linux TCP/IP stack (Android is Linux-based).